# Currently using multiple left joins in SQL Server - is there an easier way?

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have a SQL statement that produces the correct results however the statement is quite long and probably poorly formed. Does anyone have any recommendations on shorten the statement?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(b.priceRRP) AS tomi, 
    COUNT(c.priceRRP) AS mac, 
    COUNT(d.priceRRP) AS well, 
    COUNT(bt.priceTrade) AS tomiTrade, 
    COUNT(ct.priceTrade) AS macTrade, 
    COUNT(dt.priceTrade) AS wellTrade
FROM 
    Items AS a
RIGHT JOIN 
    PriceT AS pt ON pt.internalid = a.internal_id
LEFT JOIN 
    Pricewell AS d ON d.idn = (SELECT TOP(1) idn FROM Pricewell 
                               WHERE pt.idn = item 
                                 AND CASE WHEN a.taxcode = 1 THEN a.retailPrice 
                                          ELSE a.retailPrice * 1.2 END > priceRRP 
                                 AND priceRRP <> 0 
                                 AND syncDate = '2015-10-01' 
                               ORDER BY syncDate DESC, syncTime DESC)
LEFT JOIN 
    Pricetomi AS b ON b.idn = (SELECT TOP(1) idn FROM Pricetomi 
                               WHERE pt.idn = item 
                                 AND CASE WHEN a.taxcode = 1 THEN a.retailPrice 
                                          ELSE a.retailPrice * 1.2 END > priceRRP 
                                 AND priceRRP <> 0 
                                 AND syncDate = '2015-10-01' 
                               ORDER BY syncDate DESC, syncTime DESC)
LEFT JOIN 
    Pricemac AS c ON c.idn = (SELECT TOP(1) idn FROM Pricemac 
                              WHERE pt.idn = item 
                                AND CASE WHEN a.taxcode = 1 THEN a.retailPrice 
                                         ELSE a.retailPrice * 1.2 END > priceRRP 
                                AND priceRRP <> 0 
                                AND syncDate = '2015-10-01' 
                              ORDER BY syncDate DESC, syncTime DESC)
LEFT JOIN 
    Pricewell AS dt ON dt.idn = (SELECT TOP(1) idn FROM Pricewell 
                                 WHERE pt.idn = item 
                                   AND CASE WHEN a.taxcode = 1 THEN a.tradePrice 
                                            ELSE a.tradePrice * 1.2 END > priceTrade 
                                   AND priceTrade <> 0 
                                   AND syncDate = '2015-10-01' 
                                 ORDER BY syncDate DESC, syncTime DESC)
LEFT JOIN 
    Pricetomi AS bt ON bt.idn = (SELECT TOP(1) idn FROM Pricetomi 
                                 WHERE pt.idn = item 
                                   AND CASE WHEN a.taxcode = 1 THEN a.tradePrice 
                                            ELSE a.tradePrice * 1.2 END > priceTrade 
                                   AND priceTrade <> 0 
                                   AND syncDate = '2015-10-01' 
                                 ORDER BY syncDate DESC, syncTime DESC)
LEFT JOIN 
    Pricemac AS ct ON ct.idn = (SELECT TOP(1) idn FROM Pricemac 
                                WHERE pt.idn = item 
                                  AND CASE WHEN a.taxcode = 1 THEN a.tradePrice 
                                           ELSE a.tradePrice * 1.2 END > priceTrade 
                                  AND priceTrade <> 0 
                                  AND syncDate = '2015-10-01' 
                                ORDER BY syncDate DESC, syncTime DESC)
WHERE 
    a.inactive = 0
    AND a.discontinued = 0
```

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Well, I see many queries but I will save this one ;)

Comment: Query looks very bad :)

Comment: This is a OLTP database schema built for writing. Definitely not reading. I don't see any difference in your two joins to `Pricewell`. They look like the same join.

Comment: Hi Nick, the joins change slightly based on priceTrade and priceRRP. Chris

Comment: Now I see. Next thing is you limit to a single `syncDate` but then order by it. Is that just for illustration? These kinds of `Top 1 Order by` joins are difficult to get good performance out of. So fo you have a performance issue or do you just want to know if the query can be  written differently?

Comment: Hi Nick, the syncDate is sorted as there are sometimes multiple dates in the tables that are the same but I only need the latest entry. The query runs pretty fast so not worried about performance so much. Really just wanted to see if it could be shortened at all as i have 3 of these queries one a single page producing different information. Chris

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can shorten this much. One note that you can use `outer apply` for this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM PriceT AS pt
LEFT JOIN Items AS a ON pt.internalid = a.internal_id
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) priceRRP FROM Pricewell ...) d
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) priceRRP FROM Pricetomi ...) b
...
WHERE ...
```

Also many people find it better to understand when using `left join` instead of `right join`.